# Jquery Image click not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

HI
In my project I have a Popup  image .
When the user clicks on the left part of the image it will redirect the user 
to page1.aspx. When the user clicks on the right part of the image
it will redirect the user to page2.aspx. I used JQuery for this and it works
fine in Fire fox. But it doesn't work in IE.
What could be the reason,. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
swfobject.registerObject("inhalerVideo", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf");
/* jQuery Nonsense */
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //!\: Slider nav thingy.
    $("#link_one").click(function()
    {
        var aWidth = $(this).width();
        if($(this).hasClass("closed"))
        {
            $(this).removeClass("closed").addClass("open").animate({width: aWidth + 205 + "px"}, {queue: false, duration: "fast"});
            if($("#link_two").hasClass("open"))
            {
                var bWidth = $("#link_two").width();
                $("#link_two").removeClass("open").addClass("closed").animate({width: bWidth - 205 + "px"}, {queue: false, duration: "fast"});
                $("#link_two a").hide();
            }
            $("a", this).show();
        }
        else
        {
            $("a", this).hide();
            $(this).addClass("closed").removeClass("open").animate({width: aWidth - 205 + "px"}, {queue: false, duration: "fast"});
        }
    });
    $("#link_two").click(function()
    {
        var aWidth = $(this).width();
        if($(this).hasClass("closed"))
        {
            $(this).removeClass("closed").addClass("open").animate({width: aWidth + 205 + "px"}, {queue: false, duration: "fast"});
            if($("#link_one").hasClass("open"))
            {
                var bWidth = $("#link_one").width();
                $("#link_one").removeClass("open").addClass("closed").animate({width: bWidth - 205 + "px"}, {queue: false, duration: "fast"});
                $("#link_one a").hide();
            }
            $("a", this).show();
        }
        else
        {
            $("a", this).hide();
            $(this).addClass("closed").removeClass("open").animate({width: aWidth - 205 + "px"}, {queue: false, duration: "fast"});
        }
    });
    //!\: This could all be achieved with CSS.
    $(".subnavonfirst").prev(".navoff").css("background-image", "url('images/nav_on_bg.gif')").children("a").css("color", "#fff");
    $(".subnavon").prev(".subnavofffirst").prev(".navoff").css("background-image", "url('images/nav_on_bg.gif')").children("a").css("color", "#fff");
    $(".subnavonlast").prev(".subnavoff").prev(".subnavofffirst").prev(".navoff").css("background-image", "url('images/nav_on_bg.gif')").children("a").css("color", "#fff");
    $(".subnavonlast").prev(".subnavofffirst").prev(".navoff").css("background-image", "url('images/nav_on_bg.gif')").children("a").css("color", "#fff");
});
</script>

<!-- Main Content Container -->
    <div id="mainContentContainer">

        <!-- Top Link Slider -->
        <div id="headerContainer" class="printHide">
            <div id="headerLinkContainer">
              <div id="banner_container">
                <div id="link_one" class="sub closed">
            <img class="major" src="images/patient_info.gif" border="0" />
            <img class="minor" src="images/sub_nav.gif" border="0" />
            <a href="http://www.mysite.com/files/products/uspi_nicotrol_inhaler.pdf" class="inhaler" rel="external" target="_blank"><!-- --></a>
            <a href="http://www.mysite.com/files/products/uspi_nicotrol.pdf" class="ns" rel="external" target="_blank"><!-- --></a>
        </div>
                <div id="link_two" class="sub closed">
            <img class="major" src="images/prescribe_info.gif" border="0" />
            <img class="minor" src="images/sub_nav.gif" border="0" />
            <a href="http://www.mysite.com/files/products/uspi_nicotrol_inhaler.pdf" class="inhaler" rel="external" target="_blank"><!-- --></a>
            <a href="http://www.mysite.com/files/products/uspi_nicotrol.pdf" class="ns" rel="external" target="_blank"><!-- --></a>
        </div>
                <div id="link_three" class="open"><a href="#ISIContainer"><img src="images/isi.gif" border="0" /></a></div>
              </div>            
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: A code sample would help a lot in solving your problem. We can't do much if we don't know what you are doing in the first place. ;)

Comment: Perhaps we could help more effectively if you posted some of your code?

Comment: IE Version and code example are absolutely critical.

Comment: Hi Kyle you can reach the site at "nicotrol.com/". see my comments in the below mentioned answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using an [imagemap](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)?  That way it's supported by almost all browsers, including IE.

You can also capture the `click()` event of the `<area>` tag if you wish.

EDIT: Upon looking at your site, perhaps you could bind the expanding div functionality to the image `.major` rather than to the `.sub` div.

It looks like the `.sub` div is intercepting the click event on IE, but standards-compliant browsers understand that the `.minor` picture should be rendered 'above' the `.sub` div.

Comment: Putting the code on the initial question would be better, so even if I cannot answer your question, someone else may be able to, and other people who share your problem can share the solution when/if it's posted.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code. But the javascript is compressed .Why? Is there any way to correct it.